# update table from data base from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
update [Netlication].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction]
set [Netlication].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction].[atCreateDate]=[test4].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction].[atCreateDate]
from [Netlication].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction],[test4].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction]
where [Netlication].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction].[z1SISStockTransactionId]=[test4].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction].[z1SISStockTransactionId]
```

whats the wrong in this statement?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow , please take a moment to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: There are numerous things wrong with that query.

Answer (score 0):

Try below .you are missing join

```
UPDATE [Netlication].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction]
SET [Netlication].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction].[atCreateDate] = [test4].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction].[atCreateDate]
FROM [Netlication].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction] INNER Join
     [test4].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction] ON [Netlication].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction].[z1SISStockTransactionId] = [test4].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction].[z1SISStockTransactionId]
WHERE [Netlication].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction].[z1SISStockTransactionId] = [test4].[dbo].[SISStockTransaction].[z1SISStockTransactionId];
```

Comment: The objects "test4.dbo.SISStockTransaction" and "Netlication.dbo.SISStockTransaction" in the FROM clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to distinguish them  whats mean this error